# Looping through Datatables Selecting data C#

Tags: c#, loops

Below is some code which brings through a batch of multiple XML files and adds them to their own data table within a dataset:

```
    private void Btn_Import_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        /*ILRChecks.ILRReport.NullChecks();
        ILRChecks.ILRReport.CrossYear();*/

        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        DataTable diff = new DataTable();
        diff.TableName = "Differences";

        diff.Columns.Add("LearnRefNumber");
        diff.Columns.Add("ULN");
        //diff.Columns.Add("FamilyName");
        //diff.Columns.Add("GivenNames");
        diff.Columns.Add("DateofBirth");
        diff.Columns.Add("NINumber");
        diff.Columns.Add("Message");

        Dictionary<int,DataTable> Tables = new Dictionary<int,DataTable>();


        foreach (string str_FileLocation in Global.fileNames)
        {
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(str_FileLocation);
            string str_xmlFileName = fileInfo.Name;

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(str_FileLocation);

            var ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
            var learner = doc.Descendants(ns + "Learner");

            string shortfile = str_xmlFileName.Substring(13,4);

            StringReader reader = new StringReader(new XElement("Sample", learner).ToString());

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(reader);

            Tables.Add(int.Parse(shortfile), ds.Tables[0]);

            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0].Copy();
            dt.TableName = shortfile;

            dataSet.Tables.Add(dt);
        }
```

Then from here, I then want to be able to then loop through each of these datasets, comparing them, in order of the data table name. The names have been turned into Integers and need to start at the latest year, so 1819, then 1718 and so on, depending on how many files there are. 
I believe I have a working foreach statement allowing a loop to get the order of tables right and put them into a current item table:

```
        foreach (var item in Tables.OrderByDescending(k => k.Key))
        {

            if (item.Key != Tables.OrderByDescending(k => k.Key).Last().Key)
            {
                DataTable dataTable_CurrentItem = item.Value;


            }

            }
```

Then from here, I have a part of code, which works standalone, but I need to incoorporate this into the above as part of the loop, comparing the files as it goes through, but I suspect this part isn't quite right, and whether or not it should go in the foreach statement above, i'm not sure:

```
       var diff_ULNDOB = from Latest in dataSet.Tables["1819"].AsEnumerable()
                                 join previous in dataSet.Tables["1718"].AsEnumerable()
                                 on Latest.Field<string>("ULN") equals previous.Field<string>("ULN")
                                 where Latest.Field<string>("DateofBirth") != previous.Field<string>("DateofBirth")
                                 select new { ULN = Latest.Field<string>("ULN"), FamilyName = Latest.Field<string>("FamilyName") };

        if (diff_ULNDOB.Any())
        {.
            MessageBox.Show("PROBLEM!!!!!!");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See changes below.  You do not need to use DataSet.  You can use just DataTable. :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication100
{

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }


    }
    public class test
    {
        private void Btn_Import_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            /*ILRChecks.ILRReport.NullChecks();
            ILRChecks.ILRReport.CrossYear();*/

            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            DataTable diff = new DataTable();
            diff.TableName = "Differences";

            diff.Columns.Add("LearnRefNumber");
            diff.Columns.Add("ULN");
            //diff.Columns.Add("FamilyName");
            //diff.Columns.Add("GivenNames");
            diff.Columns.Add("DateofBirth");
            diff.Columns.Add("NINumber");
            diff.Columns.Add("Message");

            Dictionary<int, DataTable> Tables = new Dictionary<int, DataTable>();

            foreach (string str_FileLocation in Global.fileNames)
            {
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(str_FileLocation);
                string str_xmlFileName = fileInfo.Name;

                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(str_FileLocation);

                var ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
                var learner = doc.Descendants(ns + "Learner");

                string shortfile = str_xmlFileName.Substring(13, 4);

                StringReader reader = new StringReader(new XElement("Sample", learner).ToString());

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                dt.ReadXml(reader);

                Tables.Add(int.Parse(shortfile), dt);
            }
            var orderTables = Tables.OrderByDescending(k => k.Key).ToList();
            for (int i = 1; i <= orderTables.Count(); i--)
            {

                var diff_ULNDOB = from Latest in orderTables[i].AsEnumerable()
                                join previous in orderTables[i - 1].AsEnumerable()
                                on Latest.Field<string>("ULN") equals previous.Field<string>("ULN")
                                where Latest.Field<string>("DateofBirth") != previous.Field<string>("DateofBirth")
                                select new { ULN = Latest.Field<string>("ULN"), FamilyName = Latest.Field<string>("FamilyName") };

            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this @jdweng. Issue is now with "from latest in ordertables[i] in that is says does not contain defination for AsEnumerable, but taking this out doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Just missing Value : orderTables[i].Value.AsEnumerable()  I was getting a couple of errors because I didn't add all the libraries.  So the compiler didn't report the error you were getting.  I just added the missing libraries and now got your error.  What was strange I put Value in before I posted and compiler gave me an error so I removed Value.